# Diffeomorphism ( differential geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the Geometrical interpretation of diffeomorphism in context of differential geometry ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The wording suggests there's a unique short, correct, non-trivial answer to this somewhat vague and philosophical question. Could you please say something about where the question comes from and, if possible, what kind of insight you want? Otherwise there's not much to say besides "A diffeomorphism is something like a global change of coordinates, having no geometric effect." [As Alex Fok's answer suggests.]

Comment: I second the previous comment. A diffeomorphism is a purely topological concept. It would be great if the OP provides more background information as to how the metric structure comes into play.

Comment: @Alex: a diffeomorphism is **definitely not** a purely topological concept and it has nothing to do with metric structures.

Comment: @Georges: Thanks for pointing that out. A diffeomorphism also involves the smooth structure.

Answer (score 1):

You are given two $d$-dimensional manifolds $M$ and $N$. A *diffeomorphism* $f:\>M\to N$ is in the first place a bijective map. In addition $f$ has to relate the differentiable structures present on $M$ and $N$ in the proper way. This is accomplished if the following holds for all points $p\in M$:

Let $(x_1,\ldots, x_d)$ be local coordinates in a (suitably small) neighborhood $U$ of $p$, and let $(y_1,\ldots, y_d)$ be local coordinates in the neighborhood $V=f(U)$ of $q:=f(p)$. Then $f\restriction U$ will be described by a function
$\hat f:\ x\mapsto y$ defined in an open set of ${\mathbb R}^d$. I shall omit the hat in the sequel. It is required (a) that  $f$ is at least $C^1$ (often it is required that $f\in C^\infty$), and (b) that $df(x)$ has full rank $d$ at all points of $U$, so that $df^{-1}(y)$ is well defined at all points of $V$.

A diffeomorphism $f$ maps smooth curves $\gamma$ in $M$ to smooth curves in $N$, and its differential $df$ maps a tangent vector to $\gamma$ attached at $p$ to the tangent vector to $f(\gamma)$ attached at $q$.

One more thing: Maybe both $M$ and $N$  are a priori equipped with a Riemannian metric or a distance function. A diffeomorphism does not care about these metrics, nor about angles. It just harmonizes with  the "differentiable structures" on $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 0):

A diffeomorphism on a Riemannian manifold pulls back the metric tensor to another metric tensor.